How in laravel 10, with passport auth, get user_id or token_id from access_token?
If i have only token like:
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiI.....
How i can retrive user_id or token_id from that token?
In case the token has expired, I want to get the user’s identifier so that I can then get all of his tokens in order to delete them.
